# Convert a string in a label to int not working properly

Tags: c#, int32

I have the following code:

```
int a = Int32.Parse(weight.Text);
double b = 0;

if (this.wcf.SelectedItem == weighing)
{
    b = (a * 1.03) / 1000;
    wll.Content = b.ToString();
}
```

`weight` is the name of a `TextBox` and in this `TextBox` where the input is made  which is `50000`. `wll` is a `Label` where the calculation of `b` is shown. `wll` shows `51.5` which is correct.

I want to use the value of `b` in a calculation further down and therefore I have defined a new `int`:

```
int p = Convert.ToInt32(b);
double g = 0;          

double sq = Math.Sqrt(50 / p);
```

The value of sq should then be `0,985` and is shown in the label `daf`, but the program shows `1,492`. Something is not correct here, can anyone help me?

```
g = (1.09 + (0.41 * sq));
daf.Content = g.ToString();
```

Comment: Be careful with integer divisions. You should use doubles IE 50.0 not 50

Comment: I've tried Math.Sqrt(50.0 / p) and I got the same result.

Comment: @Ian I will try to investigate and see if I can find any mistakes. But the conversion of the value in the label to an int is done correctly?

Comment: @ThomasEikjeGjerde if your `weight.Text` is of the form `50000` or `5000` or `111111`. Then it is ok. ;) but let say it is of the form `12.131`, or `156.41`, or `50.1213`, then it is *not* ok. Basically, you need to find parser which suits with your `string` format. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of this:

```
int p = Convert.ToInt32(b);
double g = 0;          
double sq = Math.Sqrt(50 / p); //int/int
```

this will make you have `Math.Sqrt(int)`, losing precision. Instead, you should do:

```
double sq = Math.Sqrt(50D / p); //double/int
```

or

```
double sq = Math.Sqrt((double)50 / p); //double/int
```

or

```
double sq = Math.Sqrt(50.0 / p); //double/int
```

Declare `50` as `double`

In addition, since your `b` can have result of non-integer, you may want to change this line too:

```
int p = Convert.ToInt32(b); //same issue losing precision
```

into

```
double p = Convert.ToDouble(b); //use double instead
```

Comment: I declared 50 as a double both with and without decimals. That didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the convertion to a double a helped!

Comment: @ThomasEikjeGjerde great! That being the real culprit then... ;)

Answer (score 0):

One of the main thing that i can see is that in your code you have used

```
int p = Convert.ToInt32(b);
```

this will make p = 51 and not 51.1

your code should work fine if you make p as double, and convert to double

```
double p = Convert.ToDouble(b)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the convertion to a double a helped!

Comment: You are welcome. Always keep an eye on what precision you are working on and what datatype you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are converting `b` into an `int`. so you're losing the 0.5 precision, becoming 51, not 51.5. Change your `p` into a `double` and don't convert `b`! that will give you `sq` as `0,985`. Then you are printing out `g`, not `sq`. that's why the program is showing `1,492`, not `0,985`:

```
daf.Content = sq.ToString();
```